# accounts-meld not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

Accounts-meld is not working for me, should it work out the box or do I need to do something? I am rolling my own ui and using Meteor.loginWithXX() for Facebook and Twitter. I have tried creating an account manually then logging in with a third party however it just creates a new user and doesn't merge them.

Am I doing something wrong?

I am configuring my services with

```
Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
    "service": "facebook",
    "appId": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "secret": "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
});

Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({
    "service": "twitter",
    "consumerKey": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "secret": "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
});
```

Then I use  Meteor.loginWithFacebook(); and Meteor.loginWithTwitter();

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Let me post the code I'm using and you can let me know if it's helpful. It's not my code and was gleamed from other answers but from so many I can't provide sources.

Your right to use service configuration to set up each service but you do need to install the package for that if you haven't already.

I then added an event that looks something like this for each login service I offer.

```
Template.login.events({
  "click #loginWithFacebook": function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    Meteor.loginWithFacebook({

    }, function(error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I also then have an onCreateUser code block which does a check to see if it's a new user or if they are just using a new service as their login provider. This has been tweaked a little so you will need to take out the stuff that's not relevant.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  var email, oldUser, service; 

  if (user.profile == null) {
    user.profile = {};
    if (options.profile != null) {
      user.profile.name = options.profile.name;
      user.profile.organisation = options.profile.organisation;
    }
  }

  if (user.services != null) {
    service = _.keys(user.services)[0];
    email = user.services[service].email;
    if (email != null) {
      oldUser = Meteor.users.findOne({
        "emails.address": email
      });
      if (oldUser != null) {
        if (oldUser.services == null) {
          oldUser.services = {};
        }
        if (service === "google" || service === "facebook") {
          oldUser.services[service] = user.services[service];
          Meteor.users.remove(oldUser._id);
          user = oldUser;
        }
      } else {
        if (service === "google" || service === "facebook") {
          if (user.services[service].email != null) {
            user.emails = [
              {
                address: user.services[service].email,
                verified: true
              }
            ];
          } else {
            throw new Meteor.Error(500, "" + service + " account has no email attached");
          }
          user.profile.name = user.services[service].name;
          user.profile.organisation = Organisations.find({}, {'fields': {'_id':1}}).fetch()[0];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return user;
});
```